# Image background change in HTML like “life.com”

Tags: html, css, graphics

Does anybody know how to achieve an effect of smoothly changing the background color like in [life.com](http://life.com)'s header logo?

Comment: This would be done with javascript, you can look up jQuery plugins.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using JQuery UI's animate method. This allows you to change CSS properties such as the background over a certain time period. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

They are using javascript to periodically change the background color of the div that contains the logo image.

Answer (score 1):

here you are the same effect:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 spectrum(255, 255, 255);
}); 

 function spectrum(i, j , k){

    var hue = 'rgb(' + i + ',' + j + ',' + k + ')';
    $('body').css( { backgroundColor: hue });
    var i = i-1;
    if(i < 1) { var j = j-1; }
    if(j < 1) { var k = k-1; }
    if(k < 1) { var i = 255; var j = 255; var k = 255;}
    setTimeout ( "spectrum(" + i +"," + j + "," + k + ")", 100 );
 }

</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use something like [**hover fade redux**](http://greg-j.com/static-content/hover-fade-redux.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 setInterval ( "spectrum()", 1000 );
}); 

 function spectrum(){
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $('body').css( { backgroundColor: hue });

 }

</script>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```